# autoNumeric JS doen't allow me to put decimals

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Here i use autoNumeric JS.In my code it doesn't allow me to put decimal points

Code

```
 $('.input-qty').autoNumeric('init', { vMin: 0, mDec: 0 }); // It only allows 1,2 like numbers it doen't allow 1.5 like decimal points
```

Answer (score 3):

From : https://github.com/BobKnothe/autoNumeric :

```
"vMin" - controls the minimum value allowed
vMin: '0.00' (default)

"mDec" - overrides the decimal places that that are set via the vMin/vMax values
mDec: null (default method)
example - mDec: '4'
```

So you set zero decimal places. Change you code to allow decimals :

```
 $('.input-qty').autoNumeric('init', { vMin: 0, mDec: 2 });
```

Comment: thanks. just removed  'init', { vMin: 0, mDec: 2 }) .. then it's OK

Comment: @TechGuy Since this answer is the right one, please accept it